When Literate Programming, how to Increase depth of sectioning in ltxdoc? (want subsubsubsections) Structuring alternatives?
I am working on a literate programming project which used ltxdoc and the docmfp package so as to work with Python and OpenSCAD code:
\documentclass[twoside]{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{docmfp}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[draft=false,
            plainpages=false,
            pdfpagelabels,
            bookmarksnumbered,
            hyperindex=false
           ]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
  \@mparswitchfalse
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\MakeUppercase}[1]{#1}
\pagestyle{headings}
\EnableCrossrefs
\CodelineIndex
\usepackage{makeidx} 

which works well, but my current scheme of divisions breaks down at the bottom --- I am using:

\section for files
\subsection for major concepts within those files
\subsubsection for dividing concepts into sub-topics, or often, a group of modules

I'd like to have a \subsubsubsection for individual modules --- or some reasonable equivalent --- what could be used thus?
Similarly, is it possible to pretty-print the macrocode blocks in the typeset PDF?

\subsubsubsection is already \paragraph, just change the way it shows if you don't like it.

Can a \paragraph be referenced or numbered? I get the number of the section it is in, though the hot-link goes to the right place? Looking into that now.

Use \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} to get numbered \paragraphs, then \label and \ref will work on it. Control whether it goes into the ToC using \setcounter{tocdepth}{<whatever>}.

Thanks! Was coming back to note that I'd found that.
